# Access a parent class from an enum

Tags: swift, enums

So I created a class and typecasted one of the variables to be from an enum i created.  The enum has  a variable named description that I call and put on the page so that as the variable changes status its description on the page will update.

That part is fine and dandy.  But I would like to put a variable in the description, but have it reference the variable from its object from that class.

Here is an example:

```
class room: NSObject{
    var roomNumber :Int
    var status: requestStatus = .none
    var assignedAssociate: String?

    init(roomNumber:Int){
        self.roomNumber = roomNumber
    }
}

enum requestStatus {
    case waitingForHelp = "Waiting For Help"
    case beingHelped = "Being helped"
    case requestClosed
    case none

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .waitingForHelp: return "Needs Help\n "
        case .beingHelped: if return "Being Helped\n by \(super.assignedAssociate)"
        case .requestClosed: return "Completed"
        case .none: return ""
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I would like to reference assignedAssociate from the object that was instantiated from the room class inside the description for the enum beingHelped.

I just wrote in super.assignedAssociate so that you could see kinda what I wanted to do.

Oh and before everyone jumps on me, I have spend a while trying to find the information on this but swift is still so new its hard to find good sources for this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things do not automatically know what contains them (this is true in every language I know). You will need to store the information in the enum using associated data. For example, I would probably implement it this way:

```
struct Room {
    let roomNumber: Int
    var status: RequestStatus?

    init(roomNumber: Int) {
        self.roomNumber = roomNumber
    }
}

enum RequestStatus {
    case WaitingForHelp
    case BeingHelped(associate: String)
    case Closed

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .WaitingForHelp: return "Needs Help"
        case .BeingHelped(let associate): return "Being Helped by \(associate)"
        case .Closed: return "Completed"
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I removed `assignedAssociate`. This was intentional. Instead, that information is attached to the status when the status is `BeingHelped`.

Also note that I removed the `.none` case. If the status may be "nothing" that is generally better indicated with an `Optional`. If you really do want an "unassigned status", then you should call it `Unassigned` or something similar. `None` looks too much like `Optional.None` and this can lead to surprising compiler behavior. (Also note that all types and enum values should have a leading cap.) Personally, I'd probably just get rid of the `Optional`, too. Can there really be "no status?"

Comment: So when I change the status  I would do so like :
room.status = .BeingHelped("Johnny") ?

Comment: Correct. You'd pass the associate information as part of the status.

Comment: I understand what you are saying the the none status, its like an available status, and after reading your note about the compiler I would probably go with that.  It was just confusing because I also have an occupancy variable and it made it confusing. 
Also thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that in many languages (eg. java), embedded classes (which isn't the case here, but it's what he's wanting to do) do have "automatic" access to their outer class.  That said, swift doesn't allow inner classes access to their outer class, so it's just a nit with the "this is true in every language", part :)

Comment: @DavidBerry How do you access the instance you're a property of in Java? Even if `RequestStatus` were an inner-type of `Room` (which is legal in Swift), I'm not clear how it would be able to access properties of the thing that contained it. You can access *static* members of your outer class in Java (and in Swift), but I don't see how you'd access *instance* members (like `assignedAssociate`) in either language. My Java is not the strongest language; what do you mean?

Comment: @RobNapier there really isn't any special syntax to it.  If you have an outer class with an Ivar named "name" it's accessible to inner classes with the simple reference `name`. If you need to disambiguate between inner and outer class properties (or methods) you can use `OuterClaas.this.propertyName`.  Note also, that inner classes in Java can only be instantiated in the context of the outer class (u less the inner class is declared with the `static`keyword.

Comment: That's basically the same in Swift. But the question was about accessing properties of the specific instance (not the class) that we are also a property of (i.e. the assignedAssociate of the instance we are the Status of). I don't believe that's possible in any language I know of.